# Hibernate Stored Procedure Dilemma

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

What is the best way for replacing stored procedures in your database when you are moving to Hibernate. Imagine a java application that is working on its own without Hibernate, and then one will decide to use Hibernate. What is the best practice to do that? Shall I leave those parts using stored procedures intact and one by one get rid of the stored procedure and make it a stored procedure free program? or shall I HQL to call the stored procedure?

Look at it this way, isn't using stored procedure in contrast with using Hibernate? Isn't the purpose of using Hibernate to free coder from dealing with Relational mapping? If you have to deal with Stored procedures in your application, is it worth it to deal with Hibernate? If you have the knowledge and time to deal with Stored procedures, you better to use native sql rather than Hibernate?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement functionality similar to stored procedures using hibernates event system, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html

if its a good idea or not is a rather open ended question. I think, it depends on many different factors. Most importantly, what exactly are you building, what kind of team is working on it and how well is it documented.

Having things happen automatically, can be really neat, if its really well documented and if the developers actually pay attention to the documentation. Otherwise, it can lead to heaps of confusion. I suppose you have to ask the question, what is the benefits (if any) of using it, versus what the negatives are in your particular case. And make a decision based on that, I doubt very much you will find a right or wrong answer from what other people have experienced in the teams they have been working in, since it might not necessarily be appreciable for the project/team you are involved with.